# PHP/HTML/Javascript: Automatically leave page?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I've written a some PHP that interacts with a SQL database and is just around as an intermediate between two pages.

I want a user to automatically be forced to leave that page and move to another (or even a back to previous page function)

What is the easiest way to do this? I'm happy to use PHP, HTML, or JavaScript to do it.

Comment: Idont fully understand your question; pleases provide an example of what it is your trying to accomplish. Furthermore, be more specific if you cannot provide a live example.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't *force* the end user to do anything.

Comment: Hahaha, you know what I mean though. Re-directs are a necessary evil!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From php you can use the header() function to change the location:

```
header("Location: newpage.html");
```

Just be aware that if you're using header, you can't emit any html or whitespace before you make this call unless you're buffering output. Doing so will cause warnings to the effect that headers have already been sent (there is a way to work around this).

Answer (score 3):

To "move" to a page in PHP you can use the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.

Ex:    `header('Location: http://www.example.com/');`

Comment: +1 for wrapping the statement in single quotes. You only need double quotes if you are using a variable inside the ()

Answer (score 3):

In PHP I use the following code at the end of a script to move the user to the next page

```
<?php
     // MYSQL SECTION
     // PHP SECTION
     header('Location: /next.php');
?>
```

Just make sure you haven't passed any actual HTML in the page before the header code or the script will break with an error that headers have already been sent.

Comment: If you are not using a variable inside that statement, you only need single quotes; otherwise, you will need double quotes.

Comment: @RPM you're absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out. To clarify for others however the double quotes will still work without a variable however, if you're setting $location = '/next.php'; then the double quotes are needed in the code. Thanks again mate

Comment: It's a trivial facet of the answer to the question, but I believe knowing it will be better for the long run.

Comment: Definitely agree mate, it is 1 of those details that help but are easy to forget and I appreciate the reminders :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you script just interacts with SQL database and does not output anything just simply send a redirect header.

```
<?php

// sql interaction code goes here.

header('Location: /uri/to/secondpage.php');
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

from PHP you can call JavaScript by this way

```
     echo "<script>document.location.href = \"yourpage.php\"</script>";
```

This code wont bother if there any white space or html content before the line.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the php header function

```
void header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

with following example it would be more clear to you.

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

but there is some limitation with the header function in php

*Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.*

Answer (score 0):

in php

```
<?php 
  //the user must leave now
  echo"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='".$time_in_seconds."; URL=abc.com'>";//will move after the time specified,,0 can be specified to move immediately
  exit();
?>
```

in js

```
window.location="abc.com";//will move immediately,you can time using setTimeout function
```